# How to change button color while it is being clicked in Python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm making a GUI with buttons in Python with the tKinter module. I have this one button that blends in with the background so it appears that you are selecting the text (not a button) when you click on it. The issue is that when you click on it the box becomes white for a moment and it looks very ugly. I want to know how to change the color of the button as you are clicking on it.

I've already tried looking this up with no avail.

Here is a simple example of what I mean:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_enter(e):
    button['fg'] = 'yellow'

def on_leave(e):
    button['fg'] = 'green'



win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Example")
win.geometry("600x400")
win.state('zoomed')
win.configure(background='blue')

button = tk.Button(win, height=3, width=10, borderwidth=0,  text='Example', font=("Helvetica", 40), bg="blue", fg="grey",)
button.pack()
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

button.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
button.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the argument `activebackground`:

```
button = tk.Button(..., activebackground = "yellow")
```

It will change the color of the button when it is being pressed.  Similarly, you can use `activeforeground` to change the color of text of the being pressed button